# Installing .bin file with ansible and keeping it idempotent

Tags: linux, ansible

I can't find any confirmed examples of installing .bin files from a local directory (on RH7) and keeping it idempotent (pkg, file or script modules?). 
I also need to pass arguments for the installation prompts with a text file and variables or command line variables.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First use the [copy module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/copy_module.html) to copy the binary to the target machine. And than use the [shell module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/shell_module.html) to execute the binary with what ever arguments are necessary.

**But** this will never be idempotent, if the executed binary is not idempotent.

Ansible is not not idempotent in general. Ansible is just idempotent, if you restrict yourself to modules, which are idempotent. And in particular the shell module has no chance to be idempotent, if the executed commands are not idempotent.

If the binary is not idempotent, you have to write a wrapper around the binary to ensure idempotency.